# Predicting GLMs

Tags: r, regression, glm, mlogit

After I split my data frame into a training and test set, I made 2 logit regression tables with the training set. Now I need to use those models to predict the outcome of the test set and use both models to create a table comparing the predicted vs actual outcomes of the test set. How do I do this?

Comment: Use the `predict` function. `predict(model,newdata=test_set)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.